# Insert text inside canvas

Tags: html

I want to do something very basic.

I have this div with a canvas and a button. I want to write "Signature 1" inside the canvas, in the center.

How can I achive that?

```css
.signatureCanvas {
    border:1px solid #027C8C;
    width: 100%;
}
.signatureCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="signature-div text-center">
  <canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button uib-tooltip="Upload Signature" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.uploadSignature();">Speichern <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried fillText()?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a javascript block that will add text to your canvas.

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="12px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Signature 1", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
</script>
```

Comment: isn't there a simpler way to put directly on html?

Comment: Not as far as I know.